# Parsing JSON in Oracle with attribute longer than 4000

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to parse JSON attribute with value longer than 4000 characters. This is my sample json:

```
[{
        "id": "268edbb5d111",
        "name": "Sample Product",
        "status": "created",
        "description": "this is sample product",
        "productCharacteristic": [{
                "name": "property_1",
                "value": "abc",
                "valueType": "String"
            }, {
                "name": "property_2",
                "value": 123,
                "valueType": "Number"
            }, {
                "name": "property_3",
                "value": "2020-05-01T04:56:07.000+00:00",
                "valueType": "Date"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and this is PL/SQL code:

```
FOR x IN (SELECT *
            FROM json_table(l_response, '$[*]'
                 COLUMNS
                 id                        varchar2(255)   PATH '$.id',
                 name                      varchar2(255)   PATH '$.name',
                 description               varchar2(255)   PATH '$.description',
                 status                    varchar2(255)   PATH '$.status',
                 productCharacteristic     varchar2(4000)  FORMAT JSON PATH '$.productCharacteristic'
                 )
            ) LOOP
  -- do something
END LOOP;
```

The productCharacteristic attribute might be longer than 4000 but changing its datatype to VARCHAR2(32000) compiles the package with ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype and changing to CLOB returns ORA-40484: invalid data type for JSON_TABLE column. Is there maybe a way to pass the whole array of productCharacteristic as JSON and parse it inside of the loop?

Thanks.

Comment: did you enable extended varchar's in your database init parameters? MAX_STRING_SIZE https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html#GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C

Comment: I'll keep that as a final solution if nothing else works. I'm not sure if client's DBA will allow this.

Comment: As alternative, if you have APEX installed on the database ( at least 5.1.4 ) you can use APEX_JSON.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? CLOB is allowed from 18c (but I think not 12cR1 or 12cR2).

Comment: Unfortunately, APEX is not installed.

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: OK.. so what do you mean by "parse it inside of the loop" - do you really want the individual fields from each element in the array?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there maybe a way to pass the whole array of productCharacteristic as JSON and parse it inside of the loop?

It might not be quite what you want, but you can get all the array elements flattened out with [nested path](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#CJAGFIBD):

```
FOR x IN (SELECT *
            FROM json_table(l_response, '$[*]'
                 COLUMNS
                 id                        varchar2(255)   PATH '$.id',
                 name                      varchar2(255)   PATH '$.name',
                 description               varchar2(255)   PATH '$.description',
                 status                    varchar2(255)   PATH '$.status',
                 nested path '$.productCharacteristic[*]'
                   COLUMNS  (
                     product_name          varchar2(255)   PATH '$.name',
                     product_value         varchar2(4000)  PATH '$.value',
                     product_value_type    varchar2(255)   PATH '$.valueType'
                   )
                 )
            ) LOOP
  -- do something
  dbms_output.put_line(x.id || ' ' || x.product_name || ' ' || x.product_value);
END LOOP;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f47f4bd541e4fc5fee9fabbc3289eba)

Comment: Yeah, nested path was also one of the solutions I tried, it's not exactly what I need but I'll make it work. There is a database upgrade to 19c planned (not right now, maybe in few months), so I will be able to use CLOB as JSON datatype, till then nested path will do. Thanks.